# Can I take a boat down the Mosel river from the vicinity of Trier to Koblenz

Tags: germany, riverboats

My father remembers travelling by boat from the vicinity of Trier to Koblenz, some 25 years ago. Now he would like to travel by boat again on the Mosel to Koblenz (and maybe back again some days later). So far I have found one company organizing a similar journey in the opposite direction from Koblenz to Cochem : https://www.k-d.com/en/cruises/scheduled-cruises-on-the-moselle/

Are there any other companies offering such trips. We are not looking for one-day roundtrip cruises, as these are offered abundantely.

Comment: On a train along that route recently, I remember seeing some boats that certainly looked like multi-day cruises (passenger cabins, etc).

Answer (score 4):

KD, which you found is large an well known, but to my knowledge does not offer any longer tours over night.

http://www.flusskreuzfahrten.de/ seems to be a search site for river cruises, but is not available in english. However, the only organizer for cruises on the Mosel found by this page is https://www.nicko-cruises.de/en (english)

They offer an 8-day trip from Trier to Frankfurt, via Koblenz on day 4. I didn't dig too deep into their offers and don't know if they offer Trier-Koblenz only, but I thinks that's the page where to look for your trip.